# How to get notified in the progress of the operations in ExcelStorage of FileHelpers

Tags: c#-4.0, filehelpers

Documentation http://www.filehelpers.com/example_progress.html saying
that i need to use method `SetProgressHandler`  but `ExcelStorage` does not have it.

`ExcelStorage` has method `public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> Progress;`
so looks like i need to use it in some way?

```
ExcelStorage provider = new ExcelStorage(typeof(MyModel));

provider.StartRow = 2;    
provider.StartColumn = 1;                
provider.FileName = @"C:\Customers.xlsx";    
provider.HeaderRows = 13;

provider.InsertRecords(data.ToArray()); // need to get progress here
```

May be some one could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
provider.Progress += provider_Progress;
```

and then define the `provider_Progress` event handler to update

```
static void provider_Progress(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{
     var percent = e.Percent; 
     var positionMax = e.TotalRecords; 
     var position = e.CurrentRecord; 

     // update the progress control

     Application.DoEvents(); 
}
```